# 'model' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a project in Django and I'm having trouble, I'm trying to get the ID of objects in my database, but when I run it the object seems to not have an ID. Here is my model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

    class film(models.Model):

        filmName = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=120)
        quotient = models.FloatField()
        rating = models.FloatField()
        gross = models.IntegerField()
        star = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        releaseDate = models.DateField()

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.filmName
```

and in my view:

```
objects = film.objects.filter(filmName__startswith=letter)
for object in objects:
    print object.id
```

I get an error saying id does not exist and I'm not sure why

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've explicitly told Django that filmName is the primary key, so there is no separate ID.

It's not usually a good idea to do this, though.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the reply, so if I change filmName to just unique = true this should work? Also if I do this will I have to reset the database?

Comment: Yes, and probably; you might be able to manage it with migrations but probably better to start from scratch.

Comment: I tried running migrations and it seems to have messed up the database, how would I go about starting from scratch?

Comment: Are you using sqlite? If so just delete the db.sqlite3 file, and also the contents of the migrations directory.